# How to find the new path of a renamed file whose original name is known?

Tags: git, refactoring, git-bash

Consider following usecase:

I'm working on my local branch while refactoring has been done on the main branch. Now some files (classes) have been renamed and/or moved to new locations. When merging i get lots and lots of import-errors due to missing classes.

```
--A--B--C--D--E-- (master)
   \           \
    F--G--H--I--J  (topic)
```

In `A` there are the old names wich i used in `F--G--H--I`.

In `B--C--D--E` the files are refactored resulting in new file names in `E`. This includes chained renames like

```
   B: path/to/File.java              
-> C: path/to/BetterName.java
-> D: better/package/BetterName.java 
-> E: final/package/FinalName.java
```

Now merging results in `J` with many (compilation) errors due to the missing refactorings on my branch. (Because i still refer to `path.to.File` instead of `final.package.FinalName`

In order to fix the broken build, i need to know the new names for the old classes.

Is there a git command to get all the renames that have been applied to a particular file?

Comment: does your script work? if yes I don't get your question

Comment: Yes it works but i was wondering if there is a simpler solution than the script above. As i have to do it for every file.

Comment: You need to tell `git log` to find renames with the `-M` option. Then you want to only report renames and that's done with the `--diff-filter` option. I've added more detail to my answer.

Comment: I think it is crucial to note, that a particular file has been renamed multiple times in different commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git should find the renames of the files. However, if the file has had 50% or more lines change in that file, it will no longer be considered a rename. You can change this threshold if you wish.

Here is the command to do it:

```
git log -M --diff-filter=R --stat
```

It will only show you the renames. If you want to change the threshold to something else other than the default 50%, you can just add the number to the M option:

```
git log -M90 --diff-filter=R --stat
```

will only consider a file as renamed if the contents have changed by no more than 10%

**UPDATE:**

To skip all the intermediate steps, use diff instead. Git will follow the renames for you:

```
git diff -M --diff-filter=R --name-status ..master | cut -f2-
```

when you are on your topic branch.

You can then pipe this to make a bunch of sed instructions to adjust your references.

Comment: your command is quite useful but i still have to scrape it to achieve my goal

Comment: what do you want? You can format the output to your liking. You should be able to pipe it to a few more commands if you need. You shouldn't need to walk your history.

Comment: `git log -M --diff-filter=R --name-status --reverse` provides a list of all renames in the needed order (oldest first). But i have the old name ONLY. The problem is not to find the direct rename of the old name but find all successive renames afterwards, too. Hopefully its somewhat comprehensible now.

Comment: Then let git roll up all the renames with a diff. Updated my answer.

Comment: `git log --diff-filter=RD --summary --reverse` works best for me

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a satisfying answer on the web, so i've wrote a (awkward) script to go through the logs one by one (renaming by renaming)

Using the script with above example provides the follwing output:

> `$ git history path/to/File.java`
>
> **`final/package/FinalName.java`**

I added the script to my `~.bashrc` and added a the option `alias.history=!bash -ic 'git_file_history "$@"' -` to my global git config

```
#! /bin/sh
### Takes a filename as parameter ($1)
### Echoes all filenames related to $1
function git_file_history() {
        loc_var=$1;
        old=""
        while [ "$loc_var" != "$old"  ] && [ "$loc_var" != "" ]
        do
                old=$loc_var;
                #echo $loc_var;
                hashes=$(git log --format="%P %H" -1 --follow --  $loc_var);
                status=$(git diff --name-status --find-renames $hashes | grep $loc_var);
                awks=`echo $status | awk '{print $3}'`
                loc_var=$awks;
        done 
        echo "$loc_var";
}
```