# Find new location for file in Git

Tags: git

I saw in the webserver log, that a file is being requested many times.
This file does not exist anymore, and is renamed/moved to a new location.
I have the destination for the old location `/lay/gr.js` but i need to find whats the new location or name of the file is.

The whole project is tracked with Git, and so it should be possible to find, the right commit containing changes to this file i guess.

Comment: This is no git problem when you have moved the file. Search for the file on your filesystem.

Comment: I am aware, that git is not related to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Its not a git command but if you are using linux try:

```
find ./ -name "gr.js"
```

after checkout or update project

EDIT: Check if there is something that you can use to find renamed files [how-to-find-the-new-path-of-a-renamed-file-whose-original-name-is-known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192285/how-to-find-the-new-path-of-a-renamed-file-whose-original-name-is-known)

Comment: The problem is, the file has probably also been renamed :(

Answer (score 3):

I like sufleR's answer, but to answer the git part, I'd suggest that you do a

```
git log -- yourfile
```

The last (first from the top) commit probably is the one you're looking for.